# Secret cipher code,can someone resolve the issue please

Tags: java, string, compression

Geek wants to send an encrypted message in the form of string S to his friend Keeg along with instructions on how to decipher the message. To decipher the message, his friend needs to iterate over the message string from left to right, if he finds a `*`, he must remove it and add all the letters read so far to the string. He must keep on doing this till he gets rid of all the `*`.
Can you help Geek encrypt his message string S?

Note: If the string can be encrypted in multiple ways, find the smallest encrypted string.

Example 1:

```
Input: S = "ababcababcd"
Output: ab*c*d
```

Explanation: We can encrypt the string
in following way : `"ababcababcd" -> "ababc*d" -> "ab*c*d"`

Example 2:

```
Input: S = "zzzzzzz"
Output: z*z*z
```

Explanation: The string can be encrypted
in 2 ways: `"z*z*z"` and `"z**zzz"`. Out of
the two `"z*z*z"` is smaller in length.

Expected Time Complexity: O(N)
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(N)

Constraints: 1 ≤ |S| ≤ 105

Answer:

```
public String compress(String s) {

    if(s.length()==1) return s;
        
    if(s.length()%2==0){
            if(s.substring(0,s.length()/2).equals(s.substring(s.length()/2,s.length()))) {
               return s.substring(0,s.length()/2)+"*";
            }
        }
        String left=compress(s.substring(0,s.length()-1))+s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        
        return left;
    }
```

I'm not getting proper solution from this code,but in some cases,it shows this `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in the `main` method.

Comment: Please learn how to format your code. I would recommend you at least set your editor to use spaces instead of tab chars, much easier to fix. You made a very basic mistake using `==` for string compare instead of `equals`. Please fix that first and create an [mcve], including your `main`. Or learn how to use a debugger, if you're ready for that.

Comment: By the way, if there is no key involved it is called *encoding*, or indeed *compression* but not *encryption*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make it sure that the max length of string s possible is 10^5 and not 105 (I referred the question at GFG). Since the length of string is so large that if the above method is used, then there might be some cases where the JVM might not be able to assign memory to the recursive calls of the method.

Hence it displays the `outofmemory` error as usual.

Comment: Yes it is 10^5 but how do  i set the max length to 10^5.

Comment: I could be stored easily in string data type. But here I wanted to explain that re-calling of recursive functions with strings of such large lengths could result in out of memory error. You should opt for any iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.You can refer to it.

```
   public String compress(String s) {
    // Your code goes  here
Stack<Character> st=new Stack<>();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    st.add(s.charAt(i));
}
String a="";

while(!st.isEmpty()) {
    String b="";
    if(st.size()%2!=0) {
        a=st.pop()+a;
    }
    int n=st.size();
    if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()==s.charAt((n-1)/2)){
        int i=(n-1)/2;
        int j=st.size()/2;
        while(i>=0 && st.size()>j && st.peek()==s.charAt(i)) {
            b=st.pop()+b;
            i--;
            
        }
        if(i==-1) {
            a="*"+a;
        }
        else {
            a=b+a;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(!st.isEmpty())
        a=st.pop()+a;
    }
}
return a;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).